# Cannot install antspyx (no local ITK installation found, but ITK is installed)

Tags: python, pip, itk, ants

I tried to install antspyx via `pip install antspyx`.

Why does pip not found my local ITK installation? It is installed in `/usr/lib` (package insight-toolkit installed via pacman).

Comment: Please remove the solved part from your question. This is not how we mark questions as solved. If you found a solution please post it in the answer space below. See also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed the `No local ITK installation found` message by setting the environment variable `ITK_DIR=/usr/lib/cmake/ITK-5.2`.

Additionally, I had to set the option `-DModule_GenericLabelInterpolator:BOOL=ON` in the itk pkgbuild file to avoid further issues.

Answer (score 1):

`Modules/ThirdParty/GDCM/src/gdcm/Source/MediaStorageAndFileFormat/gdcmImageChangePhotometricInterpretation.h:67:64: error: 'numeric_limits' is not a member of 'std'`

This is probably related to the version of your compiler. Or maybe ANTs build script has some errors in it. Best place for fowllow-up is [ANTs issue tracker](https://github.com/ANTsX/ANTs/issues).